# Line function doesn't work

Tags: plotting

I want to draw a vertical line like this:

```
a = 10^(1/0.0015);
Line[{{a, -5}, {a, -3}}]
```

But there is an error:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want the $x$ value to be $\approx 10^{666}$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I put my real problem down in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

The error message is obscure and not as helpful as it might be, but basically your problem is that you are asking *Mathematica* to draw a line that is so far away form the origin that its position can not be represented with machine floating-point numbers. Unfortunately *Mathematica* draws all graphics with machine floats -- probably for speed, so your line segment can't be drawn.

```
MachineNumberQ[10^(1/0.0015)]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: OK. I got it. But my problem is I need to BodePlot this function: Bo = TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + \[Omega]*0.0015), \[Omega]]; And I also want to show one horizontal and one vertical line which indicate the -3db cutoff frequency. I tried several times and it seems that the line should also be in logarithm range. The cut off frequency is 1/0.0015 but I need to plot a vertical line in x=10^(1/0.0015). Any suggestions?

Comment: @yangyang. You should submit your revised problem as new question.